# dvi output fonts blurred after upgrading to Windows 10 - pdf perfect

Tags: fonts

Using MiKTeX 2.9 and amsbook, the dvi output fonts have become blurred or furry precisely after upgrading to Windows 10 (a clean install onto a formatted disc).  In contrast, the pdf output fonts remain perfectly clean.
Is there a known remedy, please?

Comment: You could try to change the metafont mode in `YAP->View->Options->Display`.  (Untested, I don't have window10 yet).

Comment: Thank you, I selected a higher resolution printer in the options menu and that seems to have improved matters - significantly, both fonts and graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change the metafont mode in `YAP->View->Options->Display` to use one with a higher resolution. (Untested, I don't have windows 10 yet)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with  Yap using this method:

How To Fix The Blurred Text Problem In Windows 10

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-the-blurred-text-problem-in-windows-10/

It worked for me much  better than changing to higher resolution.

Comment: Link answers are not so helpful. A link could be removed at any time. You should describe the solution and keep the link for more details `;-)`